# Setting Value of Input OnSubmit using JQuery in Symfony

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I am trying to set a onsubmit function that will use the google.maps.Geocoder to set the  gps positions using the address entered by a user, my code is the following

```
    <form onsubmit="getGPSLocation()">
            <input type='text' id='search_address' />
            <input type='text' id='search_lat' hidden='hidden'/>
            <input type='text' id='search_lon' hidden='hidden'/>
            <input type='submit'/>
    </form> 

    <script>
    function getGPSLocation(){
        var string = $('#search_address').val();
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': string
        }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var pos = results[0].geometry.location;
                $('#search_lat').attr('value',pos.lat());
                $('#search_lon').attr('value',pos.lng());
            }
        });

    }
    </script>
```

The problem is that when i click submit, it does properly call the geocoder function, **but** the problem is that:

- Before the geocoder can make the request to the google server and return the
    coordinate data, the Submit function has already redirected the page.

So the question is:

How to **delay the submitting of the information untill the geocoder function has successfully completed its action**.

Comment: Where is the code that updates database ?

Comment: @blackbishop as i am using Symfony, all i have to do is get the data, which is a class containing the information, i don't know what could go wrong there, I have added the backend code in the question.

Comment: @blackbishop While checking if the data was well transmitted to the backend, i realised what the problem is. I have updated the question. Can you please look at it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [Jquery onsubmit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) function. Try this code :

```
$('#your_form_id').submit(function() {

 var string = $('#search_address').val();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': string
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var pos = results[0].geometry.location;
            $('#search_lat').attr('value',pos.lat());
            $('#search_lon').attr('value',pos.lng());
        }
    });
    
  return;
 });
```